# How can I use conda skeleton with packages that are not uploaded to pypi?

Tags: python, anaconda, pypi, conda

I am trying to use conda skeleton to build conda packages for some python packages that were not uploaded to pypi.

I cannot upload them to pypi and I don't want to have to deploy a local pypi server. They are stored on the local machine, being the results of a recent build and now I want to also build their conda packages.

How can I do this? I tried various options for `--pypi-url` but I get a `OSError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol` which tells me that skeleton expects a real PYPI and that it cannot really deal with local repositories. PIP can work with local directories without problems.

What would be the way to overcome this?

Comment: That's a great question, but someday you shouldn't have to even use skeleton if you have a decent setup.py file.  https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/794

Answer (score 7):

you do not actually have to use conda skeleton. I believe you have a module/package built within a conda env and you want to package it. if that is so then building a meta.yaml file and a build.sh (macOS) would be sufficient.

For example:
say you have a project called condabuild_sample.

**cd condabuild_sample**

*use your preferable editor and create a new file meta.yaml I use vim*

**vi meta.yaml**

*Update the meta.yaml:

```
package:
     name: <your package name>
     version: <ideally your git version>

source:
     git_path: <git link> 
requirements:
     run:
         - <a list of project import requirements>
about:
     home: <project home>
     license: <custom license file>*
```

Actually, only the tag: package is required. Rest all you can customize per your project needs.

then create another file build.sh, and provide your build instructions for your package. build.sh is executed as a bash. But you can keep it empty to learn and test.

Once you have your meta.yaml and bash.sh, run the following

**conda build condabuild_sample**

If there are no mistakes, the package gets added to a directory within your conda set up. Once this step completes successfully,

**conda install --use-local condabuild_sample**

This would add to the list of conda packages, that are available locally.
Now run, to confirm,

**conda list**

You would find the package listed with a channel = local.

You can also upload to anaconda using an anaconda client.

Reference Links that I used:
[Conda Skeleton Example](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html)

Comment: I'd add, [the conda build syntax](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html) where the first parameter is the __RECIPE_PATH__

Comment: @eric_kernfeld, thats because of the upstream that you are looking build. could you check downloading and then checking locally?

Comment: Actually, the answer was fine all along and I had just misnamed a file. I'm gonna delete my earlier comments because they are not useful.